# How to determine the collapsed state of the AjaxControlToolkit CollapsiblePanelExtender in code-behind?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

`cpe.Collapsed` seems to be always set to the initial state and not reflect the current state. Is there a direct way to determine on the server if the panel is collapsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (cpe.ClientState == "true") // panel is collapsed.
```